# Fermat's Last Theorem "$\pm k$"

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ be the set of positive integers. For $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$ we define  $$\text{Sol}(n,k) = \{(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{N}^3: |a^n + b^n - c^n| \leq k\}.$$ (The set $\text{Sol}(n,k)$ denotes the solutions of the inequality $|a^n + b^n - c^n| \leq k$ for fixed $n,k$.)

Moreover, for $j\in\mathbb{N}$ set $$\text{Inf}(j) =\{n\in \mathbb{N}: \text{Sol}(n,j) \text{ is infinite}\}.$$

Clearly, we have $\{1,2\}\subseteq \text{Inf}(j)$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$.

**Questions:**

1. Is there $j\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\text{Inf}(j)\neq \{1,2\}$?
2. Is there $j\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\text{Inf}(j)$ is infinite, and what is the smallest such $j$?

Comment: To Q1: yes, trivially, fix $n$ and $a$ and set $j:=a^n$, then any $b=c$ gives you a solution.
To Q2: yes, trivially, by same idea, $j=1$ (and $a=1$).
To be honest, your question is not really appropriate for MO.

Comment: @July That seems a bit harsh. Maybe a better comment is that the question only becomes interesting if one insists that there be infinitely many *non-trivial* solutions. Of course, then one needs to figure out what are the trivial cases. You've mentioned two of them. So let's insist that solutions have $a,b,c\ge2$ and $b\ne c$.

Comment: Apologies, it was not my intention to sound harsh. It was simply a quickly typed answer to the questions. I agree, a revised version of the question might indeed contain interesting, or even highly non-trivial math. Once some "obvious" classes of solutions are excluded, who knows, it might even turn out as hard as FLT itself.
If a revised question is posted, I would also like to kindly ask the author to choose a different notation than Inf.

Comment: Noam Elkies' work on Fermat near-misses: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/ferm.html

Comment: An infinite family of integer solutions to $a^{3} + b^{3} - c^{3} = \pm 1$ was known to Ramanujan.

Comment: @July is entirely right - the question (as is) has the solutions that July mentioned and it is not on MO-level in this form. Apologies. And thanks to everyone for their comments and answers!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A 4-variable version of the infamous ABC Conjecture says the following: Let $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$ be non-zero, satisfy $a+b+c+d=0$ and $\gcd(a,b,c,d)=1$, and no subsum of two or three of $a,b,c,d$ equal to $0$. Then for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a constant $K_\epsilon$ such that 
$$ \max\{|a|,|b|,|c|,|d|\} \le K_\epsilon \prod_{p\mid abcd} p^{1+\epsilon}. $$
Applying this to an expression of the form $a^n+b^n-c^n-k$ gives a very strong bound. Assuming that I haven't made an error (which is quite possible), I think that if $n\ge5$ (and assuming the ABCD conjecture), then for any $k$, the equation
$$ a^n + b^n - c^n = k $$
has only finitely many solutions $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $|a|,|b|,|c|$ distinct and non-zero.

Actually, I guess the same (more or less) should be true for $n=4$. The point is that the surface
$$ x^n+y^n-z^n=k $$
is of general type for $n\ge5$, so the Bombieri-Lang conjecture says that the solutions in *rational numbers* $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{Q}^3$ are not Zariski dense (lie on a finite set of curves). This also follows from Vojta's conjecture. And for $n=4$, the equation defines an affine piece of a K3 surface, so Vojta's conjecture implies that the set of integer solutions likewise lies on a finite set of curves.

So your problem fits into a general framework, and for example, these statements are known if you replace $\mathbb Z$ by the ring of polynomials $\mathbb C[t]$. And as July suggests, you might want to read about how such problems are normally written, since your notation is not at all standard (and somewhat hard to parse).

Comment: I think you mean the n-conjecture (dropping pairwise coprimality). As stated, there is counterexample to the 4-variable ABC as shown here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/185857/argument-againts-the-abcd-conjecture-with-extra-gcd-conditions

Comment: For $a,b,c,d=[1, 3*x^2 - 3*x, x^3 - 3*x^2 + 3*x - 1, -x^3]$ the radical is $3x(x-1)$ and setting $x$ large power of small number makes it at most $3(x-1)$, while $|d| = x^3$.

Comment: @joro Right, I guess I do want $a,b,c,d$ pairwise co-prime. Otherwise one has to apply Vojta's conjecture on a blow-up of $\mathbb P^3$ and figure out how the canonical bundle on the blow-up interacts with your ample divisor.

Comment: Silverman, the link in the first comment was confirmed to disprove pairwise coprime abcd by ``experts``. Are you ready to bet that pairwise abcd still stands? ;-)

Comment: @joro No, I'm willing to bet that the appropriate conclusion from Vojta's conjecture applied to an appropriate blow-up of $\mathbb P^3$ is true. But I've never done that particular calculation. Does your example give a Zariski dense set of counterexamples to pairwise coprime ABCD? If not, then it is irrelevant relative to Vojta's conjecture. If it does, then that's more interesting and it would be worthwhile figuring out exactly what Vojta's conjecture implies. (Hmmm... You have a 1-parameter family, I think, so it's simply an exceptional curve. Interesting, but not unexpected.)

Comment: Vojta's "general abc" conjecture allows exceptional subsets, so my link doesn't contradict it, it contradicts stronger  abcd conjecture. In your definition of abcd you don't mention exceptional subsets like Vojta AFAICT.

Comment: @joro Ouch, you caught me. :) I tend to treat MO like a conversation about mathematics, so as per my comment to July, I generally assume that the statement "except for the usual and/or natural exceptions and counterexamples" is understood to be appended to statements. When writing articles or books, of course, this is not allowed, but it's a common convention when mathematicians talk. And anytime one is talking about solutions to Diophantine equations in dimension greater than 1, these days it's natural to omit a Zariski closed subset (then work down inductively by dimension).

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but is there any way to prove that for $n\ge5$ the equation $a^n+b^n-c^n=k$ has a *non-zero* number of solutions for any given $k$? Or is that already implied by "finitely many solutions"?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Finitely many includes none. For given $n\ge5$, I don't know of an easy characterization of those $k$ for which the equation $a^n+b^n-c^n=k$ has at least one solution $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb Z^3$ or $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb Q^3$. There may well be some congruence conditions on $k$ that preclude solutions, I haven't tried to work it out. But even if one assumes that there are solutions in $\mathbb R$ and in every $\mathbb Q_p$, I doubt that that's enough to ensure a solution in $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 5):

Not counting the trivial solutions suggested by `July`, it is known that
an integer cube or twice a cube is sum of three integer cubes in infinitely
many ways via polynomial identities.

To get to the naturals, adjust the sign.

For $n=3$, one of the simplest is:

$$ (6kx^2)^3+(k(6x^3-1))^3-(k(6x^3+1))^3 = -2k^3$$