# Is it normal surface of general type to have infinitely many positive rank elliptic curves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, algebraic-surfaces

Cross-posted from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398024/is-it-normal-surface-of-general-type-to-have-infinitely-many-positive-rank-ellip).

I am not good at algebraic geometry and almost surely am
misunderstanding something.

Got an alleged argument against Bombieri-Lang conjecture and
would like to know what the mistake is.

One of the most simplest formulations of Bombieri-Lang conjecture
is in [Joe Silverman's answer on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214422/fermats-last-theorem-pm-k/214452#comment529948_214452), paraphrasing

> ...For a surface of general type ... the Bombieri-Lang conjecture says that the solutions in rational numbers ...are.. not Zariski dense (**lie on a finite set of curves**).

Take the affine surface over the rationals:

$$ z^6 + x^4 - y^2=0$$

According to Magma it is of general type.

Fix $z$ squarefree integer $k$. This gives quartic model
of elliptic curve $k^6+x^4-y^2=0$.

This is birationally equivalent to Weierstrass $$v^2=-4k^6u+u^3 $$

As $k$ varies, this gives infinitely many positive rank elliptic curves.

> What is wrong with this alleged contradiction?

---

Comment suggests it might be not of general type.

In Magma online:  http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/

```
 K<x,y,z,t>:=ProjectiveSpace(Rationals(),3);
 p:=z^6 + x^4*t^2 - y^2*t^4;
 S:=Surface(K,p);
 KodairaEnriquesType(S);
 KodairaDimension(S);
 //returns:
 // 2 0 General type
 // 2
```

---

**Added** The main misunderstanding was caused by incorrect usage of
Magma function. The correct way to check is `KodairaEnriquesType(S : CheckADE := true);` because of certain assumptions, but this might take much longer.

With this change I get error and no result.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that the KodairaDimension function is only meant for mildly singular surfaces. The webpage http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1354 lists the related function KodairaEnriquesDimension as only working for surfaces with ADE singularities.

Comment: A general type surface (in characteristic 0) cannot be swept out by a family of elliptic curves (this follows from a short argument with pluricanonical forms.) This implies that the number of elliptic curves on a general type surface is countable; a deep conjecture (closely related to Bombieri-Lang) predicts that there are only finitely many elliptic curves.

Comment: @dhy likely you are right, thank you. After RTFM this fails:  `KodairaEnriquesType(S : CheckADE := true);`

Comment: It is worse than it might seem: your surface is unirational, and hence rational.  Probably you can find a reference somewhere, but you can also prove it directly.  For $(v,w)\in \mathbb{G}_m^2$, basically $(k^*)^2$, consider $x=w^3(v-v^{-1})/2$, $y=w^6(v^3-v-v^{-1} + v^{-3})/8$, and $z=w^2(v-v^{-1})/2$.  In other words, set $z=x/w$, and then parameterize the resulting rational curve over $k(w)$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks, will check your argument tomorrow. Two people on MSE claim it is elliptic surface, btw.

Comment: @joro: The blowing up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ in the base locus of a pencil of plane cubics is simultaneously a rational surface and admits an elliptic fibration.  There is no contradiction to being rational and admitting an elliptic fibration.

Comment: One could presumably change the $z^6$ to $z^{1001}$ and the argument that there are infinitely many positive rank elliptic curves in the surface would still seem to hold.

Comment: @eric Yes, $z^n+x^4-y^2=0$ is an elliptic surface for any $n$, as is seen by projecting to the $z$ coordinate. (Well, in any case a genus 1 fibration.) Hence it is not of general type

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am only posting this as an answer because it annoys me to see a question like this listed as "unanswered", thus "hovering" near the top of the list of unanswered questions.  If dhy wants to write up his comment as an answer, then I will delete this answer.

The surface given by the OP is as far as possible from being "general type".  Just to remind, a projective variety $S$ over a characteristic $0$ field is of **general type** if one, and hence any, smooth, projective model of the variety has big dualizing sheaf.  This is a birational property.  In particular, since the dualizing sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^n$, namely $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-n-1)$, is anti-ample, rational varieties are not of general type.  As dhy correctly points out, much more is known: for a diagram $$\begin{array}{lcc} T & \xrightarrow{f} & S \\ \downarrow \pi \\ R \end{array},$$ such that $f$ is dominant and generically finite and such that $\pi$ is projective and flat of positive fiber dimension, then the geometric generic fiber of $\pi$ is of general type (this can easily fail in positive characteristic).  In particular, if there exists a diagram as above such that the geometric generic fiber of $\pi$ is rational or an Abelian variety, then also $S$ is not of general type.  (Once upon a time, Serge Lang had a conjecture that was roughly the converse of this statement, but nobody seems to believe that conjecture anymore.)

Back to the surface $S$ of the OP, i.e., the zero locus in
$\mathbb{A}^3$ of $$F(x,y,z) = z^6 + x^4 - y^2,$$ this is an irreducible, affine hypersurface with an isolated singularity at the origin.  By the way, such a singularity is called *quasi-homogeneous*, in this case with weights $(3,6,2)$.  This came up a little while ago, because for a quasi-homogeneous function $$g:\mathbb{A}^r \to \mathbb{A}^1,$$ the critical locus of $g$ is $\{0\}\subset \mathbb{A}^1$.  Anyway, the open subset $U= D(xz)\cap S$ of $S$ is dense.  Since being of general type is birational, it suffices to work with $U$.  Denote $w = x/z\in \mathcal{O}^{\times}_{\mathbb{A}^3}(D(xz))$.  Then the defining equation of $S$ becomes, $$ \widetilde{F}(w,x,y) = x^4(w^{-6}x^2+1) - y^2.$$  Since $x$ is invertible on $D(xz)$, also $y/x^2$ is in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3}(D(xz))$.  Thus the defining equation is the same as, $$F(w,x,y) = x^4\left( 1 - \left(\frac{y}{x^2}\right)^2 + (w^{-3}x)^2 \right).$$  Now denote $$ v = \frac{y}{x^2} + \frac{x}{w^3}.$$  Then there is an isomorphism of $k$-algegras $$\frac{k[x,y,z][1/xz]}{\langle F(x,y,z) \rangle} \xrightarrow{\cong} k[v,w]\left[\frac{1}{vw}\right],$$ $$x = \frac{w^3(v-v^{-1})}{2}, \ y = \frac{w^6(v-v^{-1})^2(v+v^{-1})}{8}, \ z = \frac{w^2(v-v^{-1})}{2}.$$  In particular, $U$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{G}_m^2$.  Therefore $S$ is a rational surface.  So $S$ is not of general type.

One commenter points out that for general rational functions $a(z)$, $b(z)$ and $c(z)$, for the element $$ F(x,y,z) = x^4  +a(z)x^2 + b(z)x + c(z) - y^2,$$ of $k(z)[x,y]$, the zero locus is an elliptic surface, hence not of general type.

Comment: Thank you. Isn't much simpler argument:  treat one of the variables as parameter. If the genus is $1$ it is elliptic surface?

Answer (score 9):

This is more or less what Jason has done, but maybe a bit more direct, and it is so elementary that it's hard not to call it an exercise that possibly does not belong on MO. Start with $y^2=x^4+z^6$. Change variables $(x,y,z)=(zx_1,z^2y_1,z)$ to get $y_1^2=x_1^4+z^2$. Next change variables $(x_1,y_1,z)=(x_1,x_1^2y_2,x_1^2z_2)$ to get $y_2^2+1=z_2^2$. This eliminates a variable, so your surface is birational to $\mathbb P^1$ times the curve $Y^2+1=Z^2$. This latter curve is also trivially a copy of $\mathbb P^1$, so your surface is birational to $\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1$.  (Jason, don't delete your answer, it's great having a perspective that's more intrinsic than just "change variables and voila!".)