# Effective bounds for Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, computational-number-theory

Suppose $n>2$. By Fermat's Last Theorem, we know that $a^{n}+b^{n}=c^{n}$
has no non-trivial solutions. Can we quantify it more?

More specifically, given $a,b,c,n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n>2$ and $a^{n}+b^{n}\neq c^{n}$, can we prove lower bounds on $\lvert a^{n}+b^{n}-c^{n}\rvert$ in
terms of $a,b,c,n$? Also assume that $a,b,c$ are distinct.

Comment: I think for $n=3$ the difference $a^3+b^3-c^3$ is equal to $1$ infinitely often, so no nontrivial lower bounds probably exist.

Comment: Not duplicate but closely related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/214422/30186

Comment: I think the $a^n+b^n\neq c^n$ condition is unnecessary...

Comment: @Wojowu, yeah I had looked at that related question before posting this. Here we are more interested in the asymptotics of any lower bounds we can prove.

Comment: @GoravJindal You probably won't have much luck proving any lower bounds if we can't even (unconditionally) prove that this value tends to infinity!